# multiply values of the column for corresponding id field

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I've a table containing id and their respective values. I've to multiply the corresponding values of each id.

```
 CREATE TABLE mult_tbl(
  id NUMBER,
  val number
 );

 insert all
  into mult_tbl values (1,2)
  into mult_tbl values (1,3)
  into mult_tbl values (1,5)
  into mult_tbl values (2,2)
  into mult_tbl values (2,0)
  INTO mult_tbl VALUES (1,-1)
  into mult_tbl values (4,10)
  into mult_tbl values (4,3)
select * from dual;
```

how can i **compute row wise multiplication for each unique value of id**.
I am trying to get the output as showing id and their respective results after multiplying
the corresponding values.

> 

- for id 1, o/p -30
- for id 2, o/p 0
- for id 4, o/p 30

I am trying to implement cursor but not getting any idea.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help

```
select id,
  case
    when zer=1 then 0
    when neg=1 then -prd
    else prd
  end prd
from (
  select id, exp(sum(ln(abs(decode(val,0,1,val))))) prd
  from mult_tbl 
  group by id
) left join (
  select id,
  count(decode(val,0,val)) zer,
  mod(count(nullif(val,0)),2) neg
  from mult_tbl where val<=0
  group by id
) using(id)
```